# How can I remove \n from a string without translate, replace or strip

Tags: python, string, replace, translate, strip

I'm making a simple rpg and I'm trying to add a feature where the user can type 'save' and their stats will be written onto a txt file named 'save.txt'.

Here is the code for the saving:

```
elif first_step == 'save':
    f = open("save.txt", "w")
    f.write(f'''{player1.name}
    {player1.char_type}
    {player1.life}
    {player1.energy}
    {player1.strength}
    {player1.money}
    {player1.weapon_lvl}
    {player1.wakefulness}
    {player1.days_left}
    {player1.battle_count}''')
    f.close()
```

But, I also need the user to be able to load their saved stats. So they would enter 'load' and their stats will be updated.

I'm trying to read the txt file one line at a time and then the value of that line would become one of the variables for the player stats.
If I do this without converting it first to a string I get issues, such as some lines being skipped as python is reading 2 lines as one.

So, I tried the following:

```
elif first_step == 'load':
    f = open("save.txt", 'r')        
    player1.name_saved = f.readline()
    player1.name_saved2 = str(player1.name_saved)

    player1.name = player1.name_saved2

    #player_name is fine but when I print char_type I get 'wizard/n'

    player1.char_type_saved = f.readlines(1)
    player1.char_type_saved2 = str(player1.char_type_saved)
```

I tried the following to remove the brackets and \n

```
final_player1.char_type = player1.char_type_saved2.translate({ 
ord(c): None for c in "[']\n" })
```

Deletes the brackets but the \n is still in there.

I've also tried:

```
final_player1.char_type = final_player1.char_type.replace("\n", "")
```

If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: please provide your code in the question

Comment: can you show us the code you tried and the expected result, so we can help more?

Comment: If you see `\n` literally in the file, that must be in the string that you wrote.

Comment: And clarify whether it is  `\n` or `/n` you have a problem with!

Comment: How are you reading the lines of the file? That may be at least part of the problem.

Comment: You may need to replace `r"\n"` string (2 characters) rather than `'\n'` a single newline character. If that's the case try `file_contents.replace(r'\n', '')`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I've just updated my question with more info. I'd be grateful for any insight on this. Let me know if you'd like to see the entire program as I'm not sure the above will suffice. Thanks again

Comment: \n wasn't in the file it was only when after I'd read from the file and printed it in the terminal

Comment: In the end, I used JSON and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong. But my guess is that you are using the original string without realizing it.

Take a look at this example code. Buf still has the newline but replacedBuf doesn't.

```
buf = "a string\n"
replacedBuf = buf.replace("\n", "")
print (buf)
print (replacedBuf)
```

Comment: By the way, this is called immutability.  You may want to lookup "python string immutable" or similar search. There are plenty of good articles on the subject.